# Call different viewControllers on click of tab bar of UITabBarController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

Below is the image of my `UITabBarController` structure in storyboard.

[image]

Right now in storyboard, `AboutUsViewController(UIViewController)` is bound with my tabBar button click event i.e. If I click on tabBar button, `AboutUsViewController` is opening but now my functionality is based on certain conditions. I want to call `ContactRequstViewController` instead of `AboutUsViewController` on same tabBar button click.

Following is my code to open `ContactRequstViewController`.

```
-(void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController{
      if (tabBarController.selectedIndex == 2){
           UIStoryboard *story =  [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iPhone" bundle:nil];
           ContactRequstViewController *contactVC = [story instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ContactUsView"];
          [self.navigationController pushViewController:contactVC animated:YES];
      }
}
```

After writing above code I am not able to load `ContactRequestViewController`.

Comment: As far as i can see, there is no navigation controller to the `UITabbarController` so the `self.navigationController` should actually be nil and the reason why nothing is being pushed. Kindly have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to replace the root view controller at that selected tab based on custom logic, try using `setViewControllers:animated:` method of the `UITabBarController`.

You could do something like this:

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    if (tabBarController.selectedIndex == 1 && tabBarController.viewControllers.count > tabBarController.selectedIndex) {
        BOOL shouldShowContactVC = (BOOL)(rand() % 2);
        NSMutableArray *viewControllers = [[tabBarController viewControllers] mutableCopy];
        UIStoryboard *main = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
        UIViewController *newVC = nil;
        if (shouldShowContactVC) {
            newVC = [main instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ContactUsVC"];
        } else {
            newVC = [main instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AboutUsVC"];
        }
        if (newVC) {
            [viewControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:tabBarController.selectedIndex withObject:newVC];
            newVC.tabBarItem = viewController.tabBarItem;
            [tabBarController setViewControllers:viewControllers animated:YES];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I implemented your code but I am not able to load ContactRequestViewController.

Comment: @iPhone Okay, I created an example project. You can find it here: https://bitbucket.org/pranay_k/tabbarexample/commits/all. Check it out and let me know.

Comment: I implemented this too but did not get success. Let me clear one thing my code is not written in appdelegate.m file but it is in MainTabController(UITabBarController) file which is bound to Main Tab Controller in storyboard.

Comment: let me clear that my code is not written in appdelegate.m file but it is written in mainTabController(UITabController) which is bound to Main Tab Controller in storyboard file.

Comment: It doesn't matter where you set the delegate. Be it inside the AppDelegate or anywhere else.

Comment: @iPhone FWIW, I updated the example project to mimic what you described. Still works. Check it out and let me know

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am able to achieve desired result after looking into your demo.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience , sometimes we don't use tabbarVC, because it's not flexible, such as **hide**, **show**, or **change items number**. So we set a navigationVC as rootVC, u can create a View, just make it's look like a tabbarVC. 
This view is more easy to used.And u don't need to care any delegate method or something else. u can do anything u want. 
That's all.